# WalletConnect :- Client meta the app icon not showing?

Tags: react-native, web3js, wallet-connect

I am developing react native application, where I have used `@walletconnect/react-native-dapp` to connect external wallet to my app. Every thing is working as expected, only thing I am not able to setup is that when I provide clientMeta to `WalletConnectProvider` context, the other details is show but my app icon is not showing.

What I am doing wrong, here is the code which I am using.

```
<WalletConnectProvider
            bridge="https://bridge.walletconnect.org"
            // @ts-ignore
            redirectUrl={
              Platform.OS === 'web' ? window.location.origin : 'pozzleplanet://'
            }
            storageOptions={{
              // @ts-ignore
              asyncStorage: AsyncStorage,
            }}
            clientMeta={{
              description: '',
              url: 'https://myapp.com',
              icons: ['https://myapp/app-icon.png'],
              name: 'my app',
            }}>
            <AuthProvider>
              <SafeAreaProvider>
                <InitComponent />
                <NavigationRoot />
                <StatusBar backgroundColor="transparent" translucent />
                <Toast />
              </SafeAreaProvider>
            </AuthProvider>
          </WalletConnectProvider>
```

This is popup present to confirm the wallet connect request.

[image]

Instead of app icon everything is showing at this confirmation popup, someone can suggest me, how can I set my app icon as well.